# sourcefile encoding UTF-8 no-bom and Visual Studio MFC

Tags: utf-8, mfc, visual-studio-2019

I do have that simple codesnippet in a C++-File (Visual Studio 2019, MFC-Project)

```
CString teststr = _T("täst"); //second letter is a german "Umlaut"
TRACE(_T("\n%s: %d"), static_cast<LPCTSTR>(teststr), teststr.GetLength());
```

the Default-encoding of sourcefiles in VS is "Western European (Windows) - Codepage 1252" - at least on my system.

The TRACE gives me the correct text and a correct length (4).

However, I wanted to change sourcefiles-encoding to UTF-8 to be able to be developer-language-independent in the future.

If I change the encoding to "Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001)" it's still all fine, except the source-file gets a BOM - something I don't like.

The real problem occurs, when I save the source as "Unicode (UTF-8 without signature) - Codepage 65001)" (which is the encoding I would like to use). When I do that, the source-file still looks fine in the editor, but TRACE gives me: `"tÃ¤st: 5"` which of cause is horribly wrong and a source of terrible bugs and crashes in production code.

So the question is: How to save sources as UTF-8 without BOM and have it still work? Is there any setting or extension that might help here?

Comment: `TRACE` has to do narrow-to-wide string conversion. The standard MFC facilities use `MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP,...)`, not `MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8,...)`, i.e., they assume that the narrow string is in the "ANSI codepage"; but your string is actually UTF-8. Therefore, you get incomprehensible output in the Debug window.

Comment: Actually, no. Assuming you do a Unicode build, the code actually is `CStringW s = L"täst";` and it depends on how the *compiler* transforms the source code string to a wide string. Chances are that it also assumes that the source file is in CP1252.

Comment: *"the source-file gets a BOM - something I don't like"* - Why are you avoiding the solution? It is what you really want. The BOM unambiguously identifies the encoding of the document, and any consumer can take it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [`/utf-8`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/utf-8-set-source-and-executable-character-sets-to-utf-8?view=msvc-160) compiler option, specifically (emphasis mine):

> You can use the `/utf-8` option to specify both the source and execution character sets as encoded by using UTF-8. It's equivalent to specifying `/source-charset:utf-8 /execution-charset:utf-8` on the command line. Any of these options also enables the `/validate-charset` option by default. For a list of supported code page identifiers and character set names, see [Code Page Identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/Intl/code-page-identifiers).
>
> **By default, Visual Studio detects a byte-order mark to determine if the source file is in an encoded Unicode format, for example, UTF-16 or UTF-8. If no byte-order mark is found, it assumes the source file is encoded using the current user code page, unless you've specified a code page by using `/utf-8` or the `/source-charset` option.** Visual Studio allows you to save your C++ source code by using any of several character encodings. For information about source and execution character sets, see [Character Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/character-sets?view=msvc-160) in the language documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do a Unicode build, the code that the compiler actually sees

```
CStringW s = L"täst";
```

and it depends on how the compiler transforms the source code string to a wide string. The default setting in MSVC is that source files without a BOM are in the current codepage, CP1252 in your case.

You can use `/source-charset:utf-8` to tell the compiler about the actual encoding. You supply the option in the *Additional Options* field of the project settings.

[See the compiler command line option.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/source-charset-set-source-character-set?view=msvc-160)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, which are working fine (the /utf-8 compiler switch)

Now I know now problem is having different encodings in different source files and I don't want to bulk-enocode all of them as utf-8.
So I cannot tell the compiler globally how to tread no-bom files

So my solution is: Don't use utf-8 nobom with c++-sources, always use a bom or leave the existing files as CP1252.